# baking lighting into a texture in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, lighting, shadows

Ive searched all over google and all i can find is videos from 2015 or unanswered questions, so if any of you could help, id be really thankfull.

I want to bake some shadows into a pretty simple character im making, so when its animated the reflection doesnt change, anyone know how can i do that?

I have a 2048x2048 black texture that isnt really applied anywhere, being where i want to bake into

[image: The material that i need to bake]

[image: The character with a Sun light source]

Comment: Make sure to **set *Subsurface Scattering* and *Metallic* to 0** before you bake.

Answer (score 1):

As a first note, Baking is only possible in Cycles as for now.
Which brings the bad news of lacking the *shader to rgb* node.

However you can bake out matcaps from the camera view.

- Step 1 : Check this [matcap collection](https://github.com/nidorx/matcaps) - its an awesome collection of
  matcaps for almost every material!!
- Step 2 : Use [this node setup](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/70/9a/46/709a4643f1865348f8de8ffbe7ff2971.png) to render matcaps on a mesh. Connect
  your end-image color output to an emission node.
- Step 3 : UV unwrap your model with the *least number* of seams
  possible!!
- Step 4 : Position your render camera in a view that gives the desired
  lighting/shading on your mesh.
- Step 6 : [Bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html)
- Step 7 : Save the image and be prepared for a lot of [retouching](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tools.html).

Comment: There was, at one point, this experimental effort by a user to attempt to get a baking-like process to function in Eevee, but I do not know if it has been maintained (and it was non-obvious to me how to get it working again): https://devtalk.blender.org/t/baking-with-eevee/7934/11